# tvOS button background color issue where it's not set properly

Tags: colors, tvos

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to set the button's color to a very light blue, but by default everything but the bezels are being darkened. Is the default button behavior causing this? Is there a workaround besides creating your own button? If I do have to create my own button, how can I reuse the default button's animation behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find a way around it outside of a creating a custom button.  Unfortunately this also required recreating something similar to the default button's focus animation from scratch.  A lot of work just to change the button background color.

Comment: That's what I had to do as well, though I do think it's a bit ridiculous... how is this a feature? I don't want to recreate all the focus animation from scratch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a custom button.

Instead, create an image containing the color you want and use that as a background image. Plus make sure to set the button's background color to default (clearColor), otherwise you will lose the rounded corners.

Comment: Though this doesn't have the default focus animation for a button, right?

Comment: @Jaime: Wrong. Using a background image instead of a color keeps the default animations.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood what you meant. Sweet! This seems like it's the fix I'm looking for.